# Including Django Views and Templates in Django Package

Tags: python, django, python-module

I am creating a Python package that includes the core functionality of a Django webapp that I would like to use as a base for multiple future web apps.

In this context I would like to include all the basic views and templates in said module, so that the base webapp frontend/backend are the same.

I would like some tips on how this can be achieve. The inclusion of the views and templates in the Django package specifically. If somebody could point me to specific examples that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django documentation addresses this [in detail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/).

Comment: Amazing. Can't believe how I had overlooked such an obvious resource. Thank you for the quick and correct reference.